# Saving animations using ffmpeg and matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, ffmpeg, save

im new in here and new in python, im doing some animations with animation.FuncAnimation of matplotliib. The animation works perfectly but i´m having problems saving the animations. here is the part of the code of the animation.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

line,  = ax.plot(range(N),sin(x[0,:]),'o-')
ax.axis([0,1,-1,1])

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(sin(x[i,:]))  # update the data
    return line,

def init():
    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x[0,:], mask=True))
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 10000),
    interval=25, init_func=init, blit=True)
ani.save('2osc.mp4', writer="ffmpeg")
plt.show()
```

where x[:,:] is previously set. ani.save is saving every frame of the animation as a .npg image instade of saving the movie. I dont know if this is how it is suposed to work and i have to do the movie with the .npg with another program or if im doing something wrong. 
Obs: i've previously installed ffmpeg and it seems to be working just fine.

Comment: Did you install the required libraries (`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`)? Also, can you share the exact code that you run?

Comment: I did not install the required libraries but my code is working now, i closed everything, restarted pyhton and run it again and now is saving the movies just fine. Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me this code seems to be running fine:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
x=np.linspace(np.pi,4*np.pi,100)
N=len(x)
ax.set_xlim(len(x))
ax.set_ylim(-1.5,1.5)
line,  = ax.plot([],[],'o-')

def init():
    line.set_ydata(np.ma.array(x[:], mask=True))
    return line,

def animate(i, *args, **kwargs):
    y=np.sin(x*i)
    line.set_data(np.arange(N),y)            # update the data
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, 
     frames=100, interval=10, blit= False, repeat = False)
ani.save('2osc.mp4', writer="ffmpeg")
fig.show()
```

You can install the ffmpeg library by using:

`sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`

Comment: you were right, it is working fine, i had to close everything restart python and run the code again and now i have a lot of beautifull videos.^^ sorry if i make you lose your time. thks!